No redirection to Okta when trying to use Okta-hosted login
I have an ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.8 project and I'm trying to implement a login via Okta. When I click the 'Login via Okta' button on my view, all it does is refresh the page.
This is my web.config:
<add key="okta:ClientId" value="***my client ID***" />
<add key="okta:OktaDomain" value="https://not-my-real-link.okta.com" />
<add key="okta:RedirectUri" value=":https://localhost:52768/authorization-code/callback" />
<add key="okta:ClientSecret" value="***my client secret***" />
<add key="okta:AuthorizationServerId" value="default" />
<add key="okta:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:52768/authorization-code/callback" />
<add key="okta:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:5278/Users/OktaLogout" />

And here is my startup.cs file:
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(mynamespace.Startup))]

namespace mynamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions()
            {
                OktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OktaDomain"],
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientSecret"],
                AuthorizationServerId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:AuthorizationServerId"],
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"],
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
                GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
                Scope = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "email" },
            });
        }
    }
}

Here is my controller:
    public ActionResult OktaLogin()
    {
        if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                OktaDefaults.MvcAuthenticationType);
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }

        return View("Login");
   }

And finally I have a button on my view page:
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("OktaLogin", "User")'" class="formButton oktaButton">Sign In via Okta</button>

Okta has an example that I have tried following as guidance:
https://github.com/okta/samples-aspnet/blob/master/okta-hosted-login/
I have used the debugger and I am going into the Startup.cs file when the application starts. Once clicking the button, we are directed to the controller and get to the following:
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(OktaDefaults.MvcAuthenticationType);

return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();

Here HttpUnauthorizedResult() is returned. I can't work out what is going wrong or even how to go about debugging this - how can I confirm whether I am getting the correct Owin context with debugger? I am relatively knew to .NET.

I have found the issue. Cookies were disabled in my Web.Config, preventing Okta from working properly.
   <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/User/Login" protection="All" path="/" timeout="1000" slidingExpiration="true" />
   </authentication>

